# Searching string with sql contains and building "contains" expression with ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, full-text-search

Hi i have a table which contains ~180K records and i need to search string in this table.

For example if user searching something like this "Paris Restaurants"
I need to create expression like that

```
SELECT * FROM ListOfStrings
WHERE CONTAINS(Title, ' "Paris Restaurants" OR (Paris OR Restaurants) ')
```

But there could be one or more terms. So i need to create Contains expression dynamically.

I googled but i couldn't find about creating expression dynamically.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't you use `FREETEXT` in this case?

Comment: I used it but, it returns too much irrelevant results.

Comment: You need to create `CONTAINS` expression on sql or client side?

Comment: I think it should be on the codebehind, not on sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build by using a functions that accepts your search term and then splits and joins that to give your desired Contains argument.

```
public string ContainsBuilder(string searchterm)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append('"');
    sb.Append(searchterm);
    sb.Append('"');        
    sb.Append(" OR (");
    sb.Append(String.Join(" OR ",searchterm.Split(' ')));
    sb.Append(")");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

if you call this method with `paris restaurants` it returns `"paris restaurants" OR (paris OR restaurants)`

Comment: I didn't think it would be that simple. But it's worth a try thanks.